# Using regex to grab sitekey on html page

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to grab the sitekey from an html page that contains a hcaptcha. I am trying to accomplish this task using regex but it does not seem to be working. This is the page in question:

```
<iframe src="https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/captcha/v1/521551d/static/hcaptcha-challenge.html#id=079uk7m93wrr&amp;host=www.ziprecruiter.com&amp;sentry=true&amp;reportapi=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.hcaptcha.com&amp;recaptchacompat=off&amp;custom=false&amp;tplinks=on&amp;sitekey=33f96e6a-38cd-421b-bb68-7806e1764460" title="Main content of the hCaptcha challenge" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px; z-index: 2000000000; position: relative;"></iframe>
```

In this case, the sitekey is present in the `src` attribute of the iframe. `sitekey=33f96e6a-38cd-421b-bb68-7806e176446`. I specifically need the `33f96e6a-38cd-421b-bb68-7806e176446` portion.

Here is the regex I tried that did not work:

```
const regex = /siteke\w+/g;
const found = html.match(regex);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a `regex` question, but sometimes a simple string parse will do the trick using `split()`

```js
let site_key = document.querySelector('iframe').src.split('sitekey=')[1].split('"')[0];
console.log(site_key);
```

```html
<iframe src="https://newassets.hcaptcha.com/captcha/v1/521551d/static/hcaptcha-challenge.html#id=079uk7m93wrr&amp;host=www.ziprecruiter.com&amp;sentry=true&amp;reportapi=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.hcaptcha.com&amp;recaptchacompat=off&amp;custom=false&amp;tplinks=on&amp;sitekey=33f96e6a-38cd-421b-bb68-7806e1764460"
  title="Main content of the hCaptcha challenge" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px; z-index: 2000000000; position: relative;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex suggestion:

```
/(?<=sitekey=).+?(?=")/g
```

Up to you which javascript regex method you will use.